# Conjecture with a three-diagonal system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, gaussian-elimination

Everything in the sequel real-valued. And it is silently assumed that the denominators are non-zero, though the latter is not a trivial issue.
Consider a piece of an (infinitely) large system of uniform tri-diagonal linear
equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
      - a.T_0 + T_1 - b.T_2 = 0   &\quad (1)& \\
      - a.T_1 + T_2 - b.T_3 = 0   &\quad (2)& \\
      - a.T_2 + T_3 - b.T_4 = 0   &\quad (3)& \\
      - a.T_3 + T_4 - b.T_5 = 0   &\quad (4)& \\
      - a.T_4 + T_5 - b.T_6 = 0   &\quad (5)&
\end{eqnarray*}
And a boundary condition ($RHS\ne0$) somewhere, but not within our reach.
It is possiblle to use equations (2) and (4) for eliminating $T_2$ and $T_4$
from (3) and replace them by $T_1$ and $T_5$. As follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
      T_2 = a.T_1 + b.T_3    &\quad (2)& \\
      T_4 = a.T_3 + b.T_5    &\quad (4)&
\end{eqnarray*}

Giving respectively:

\begin{eqnarray*}
      - a (a.T_1 + b.T_3) + T_3 - b (a.T_3 + b.T_5) = 0 & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad & \\
      - a^2.T_1 + (1 - 2.a.b) T_3 - b^2.T_5 = 0 & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad & \\
      - \left(\frac{a^2}{1-2ab}\right)T_1 + T_3 
      - \left(\frac{b^2}{1-2ab}\right)T_5 = 0 &\quad (3,2,4)&
\end{eqnarray*}

Thus, by employing this elimination procedure, the matrix pattern:
$$
                   -a \qquad 1 \qquad -b 
$$
has been replaced by:
$$
    - \left(\frac{a^2}{1-2ab}\right)
    \qquad 0 \qquad 1 \qquad 0 \qquad  
    - \left(\frac{b^2}{1-2ab}\right)
$$
But we will go even further and eliminate the variables $T_1$ and $T_5$ from
equation (3) by employing (1) and (6) together with (2) and (4):

\begin{eqnarray*}
       T_1 = a.T_0 + b.T_2 = a.T_0 + b.(a.T_1 + b.T_3)     & \quad (1,2)& \\
       (1 - a.b).T_1 = a.T_0 + b^2.T_3                     & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad & \\
       T_1 = \left(\frac{a}{1-ab}\right) T_0 
           + \left(\frac{b^2}{1-ab}\right) T_3             &&
\end{eqnarray*}
\begin{eqnarray*}
       T_5 = a.T_4 + b.T_6 = a.(a.T_3 + b.T_5) + b.T_6     & \quad (4,5)& \\
       (1 - a.b).T_5 = a^2.T_3 + b.T_6                     & \quad \Longrightarrow \quad & \\
       T_5 = \left(\frac{a^2}{1-ab}\right) T_3 
           + \left(\frac{b}{1-ab}\right) T_6               &&
\end{eqnarray*}

Now substitute (1,2) and (4,5) into (3,2,4), then:

\begin{eqnarray*}
  - a^3/(1-2ab)/(1-ab) &T_0& \\
  + \left[1 - 2.a^2.b^2/(1-2ab)/(1-ab)\right] &T_3& \\
  - b^3/(1-2ab)/(1-ab) &T_6& = 0 
\end{eqnarray*}

And the matrix pattern has become:
$$
  - a^3.X(a,b) \qquad 0 \qquad 0 \qquad 1 \qquad 0 \qquad 0 \qquad - b^3.X(a,b)
$$
Where:
$$
  X(a,b) = \frac{1/(1-2ab)/(1-ab)}{1 - 2.a^2.b^2/(1-2ab)/(1-ab)} =
$$ $$
  \frac{1}{(1-2ab)(1-ab) - 2.a^2.b^2} = \frac{1}{1-3ab} 
$$
Hence the matrix pattern, with five equations involved, simplified:
$$
  - \left( \frac{a^3}{1-3ab} \right)
  \qquad 0 \qquad 0 \qquad 1 \qquad 0 \qquad 0 \qquad
  - \left( \frac{b^3}{1-3ab} \right)
$$
It is seen that the elimination procedure with 5 equations involved results
in a pattern which is very much alike the one with 3 equations involved:
$$
    - \left(\frac{a^2}{1-2ab}\right)
    \qquad 0 \qquad 1 \qquad 0 \qquad  
    - \left(\frac{b^2}{1-2ab}\right)
$$
This would suggest that an elimination procedure with $2n-1$ equations involved
would result in a matrix pattern like:
$$
    - a^n/(1-n.a.b) 
    \quad 0 \quad ... \quad 0 \quad 1 \quad 0 \quad ... \quad 0 \quad
    - b^n/(1-n.a.b)
$$
But this suggestion seems to be false. It is already false for $n=1$, as is clear from
$-a\ne -a/(1-ab)$ and $-b\ne -b/(1-ab)$. And it is false for $n=4$, as is clear
from $4=2\times 2$. Because herewith the function $X(a,b)$ becomes, for $n=4$ :
$$
  X(a,b) = \frac{1/(1-2ab)/(1-2ab)}
                {1 - 2\left[a^2/(1-2ab)\right]\left[b^2/(1-2ab)\right]}
$$ $$
  \frac{1}{(1-2ab)^2 - 2.a^2.b^2} = \frac{1}{1-4ab+2a^2b^2} \ne \frac{1}{1-4ab} 
$$
Can we conclude that the elimination of $(2n-1)$ equations from the given uniform
three-diagonal linear system of equations results in a pattern
$$
    - a^n/(1-n.a.b) 
    \quad 0 \quad ... \quad 0 \quad 1 \quad 0 \quad ... \quad 0 \quad
    - b^n/(1-n.a.b)
$$
but **if and only if $(n=2)$ or $(n=3)$** ? Can someone prove or disprove this **conjecture** ?